# PHPcurl: Login into Website and GET Data after Login HTTP 404 Resource not found Error

Tags: php, curl, webmail, php-curl, horde

I want to login into my Horde Webmail automatically through phpcurl and then display all my Emails. 
So far my login works perfect. 
I login with Credentials and Cookies.

**What's the Problem?**

I get my Dashboard displayed but without any Data. Here is a Screenshot how it looks like:

[image: Horde Webmail Screenshot]

**What Error Output do I get?**

In the Console it says:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here a Screenshot of my Console:

[image: Screenshot Error Output]

**What Code do I use so far?**

```
//Data
$webmail_login = "http://webmail.licht-austria.at/login.php";
$webmail_mailbox = "http://webmail.licht-austria.at/imp/dynamic.php?page=mailbox";
$login = "";
$password = '';
$postdata = "login_post=1&horde_user=$login&horde_pass=$password&horde_select_view=auto&new_lang=de_DE";

//Curl Login POST
$ch = curl_init(); 
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webmail_login );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//Until here it works i logged in

//Curl Mailbox GET
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webmail_mailbox);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

**How does my Code work?**

In the first steps I use my Credentials and Login through POST into my Webmail.
The PostData ist correct and I can Login. After webmail.at/login.php is finished, I get redirect to my Inbox (webmail.at/imp/dynamic.php?page=mailbox). 
The webmail uses GET Method now to get all the Emails and Stuff and at this moment I get the 404 Errors.

Comment: First of all do you really need login using HTTP? IMAP/SMTP is not better way?
Second thing, their webmail client can send data by ajax, curl can't handle it.

Comment: Ah ok well the problem is that i dont know much about IMAP and how to work with it. Can you provide me an example how to do that?

Comment: you dont encode username/password correctly. any password with `&` or a space (to name two) would be incorrectly encoded and login rejected. you should check out urlencode()

Comment: I dont need these two anymore because Im login through cookies now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

well, this error is not related to the curl, it's related to loading website resources into you web page .

to solve this you may work around it by :

`echo '<base href="http://www.example.com" />' . $data;`

however, it's not recommended to do this.

it will be better that you re-manipulate your response data ,

for example , if the response is a html , parse it using [Dom](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) library for example , or simply using regex , and if it a json response rebuild new simple ui to view your results .

Comment: If I do it with your echo I get this error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://webmail.licht-austria.at/services/ajax.php/imp/dynamicInit. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://service-lukas-reiner.de' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: then it will be better to you to 'manually' re-parse the curl response .

Comment: Ok ill try that. But could it also work if i allow Origin in my PHP file? I could set Origin Headers for GET Method?

Comment: i think the server you are curling which must allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the context

Comment: Yep thats true. I tried to set the Origin Headers but I get no access too.

Comment: as i told you , this will be better to re-parse your response as you want to view

Comment: Can you provide me an example how i can do that with that DOM Lib or any tutorial?

Comment: it's too complicated to explain this here in SO, you are getting html response , using regex you can split your response into rows , then looping overs this rows and extract the data you want from each row using preg_match for example , or using dom library [i'm not familiar with it] you can extract some data from your html and then create your new view through it .

Answer (score 0):

It is loading its resources using relative paths. It needs absolute paths like http://www.example.com/jquery.min.js. What you could do is to download all the resources needed from its website and place them in a src folder. The website used for example `/script.js` and now it looks for it in your project because it's relative path.